# Java Getting latest version of iOS Passbook - PKPass bundle as response

Tags: java, ios, json, rest, passbook

I am a Java API Developer trying to integrate with iOS Passbook App. I had created a PKPass bundle with Pass.json and other necessary resources. I could view the created pass in both Safari, Passbook mobile app.

Currently I am trying to update the Passes. I have exposed a service for registering the device through which I can capture device(push) token, device library identifier, pass identifier.

When I try to update the pass, I am using APNS to create the Pull request from the device. I have exposed a service for Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device and I could send the pass "serial number" and "last updated" back to the device.

Then the device hits my Getting the Latest Version of a Pass service and I am creating a new PKPass bundle. I am storing the new pkpass bundle in the server and have the bundle as a byte array in the service. I have to send back the pkpass bundle back to the device which I couldn't. I have the following queries regarding that.

1. I have created the new pass with same serial number and authentication token as the old one. Please correct me, if I am wrong.
2. I am trying to send the whole pkpass bundle with Pass.json, icon images, manifest.json and signature. Please correct me, if I am wrong.
3. What is the way to send back the latest version? As byte array or any other way?
4. I have exposed a service for logging errors but I couldn't see any error logs as well.

Simply I couldn't cross finish line in the update and everything else is working as expected till the response that I have to send for 'Getting the latest version of the pass'.

So from Java perspective, I need a Restful response entity for sending the latest version of PKPass.

Please provide some sample Java codes, if possible.

------EDIT----

Actually I have added the following headers.

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="409eedb9-bf2e-436d-bb2b-fed3c6630c66"; filename="409eedb9-bf2e-436d-bb2b-fed3c6630c66.pkpass" 
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 
Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass 
Content-Length: 28996 
Date: Fri, 17 Apr 2015 16:32:51 GMT

Comment: Send the .pkpass pass bundle the same as you would serve any web asset.  Also make sure that you have the correct content header application/vnd.apple.pkpass

Comment: I had the headers for pkpass as application/vnd.apple.pkpass.